# Is there a way to install apache oozie in windows 10

Tags: hadoop, oozie

How I can install apache oozie in windows 10, not vm
I could not find any documents.
Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest Airflow over Oozie

Answer (score 0):

Well [Oozie](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.0.0/DG_QuickStart.html#System_Requirements) isn't supported on windows:

> Server Installation
> System Requirements Unix (tested in Linux and Mac OS X) Java 1.8+
> Hadoop Apache Hadoop (tested with 1.2.1 & 2.6.0+) ExtJS library
> (optional, to enable Oozie webconsole) ExtJS 2.2 The Java 1.8+ bin
> directory should be in the command path.

You might be able to use Cygwin to make it work but I haven't tried it and I'm sure it would be a challenge.  Basically, it's not supported but if you forced me to try and make it work I'd use Cygwin.

Comment: WSL2 should be preferred over Cygwin